# No plugin to handle input format: doc - Calibre

Tags: python, calibre

I am trying to convert a doc to an epub using calibre via the command line but I get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site.py", line 61, in main
  File "site-packages/calibre/ebooks/conversion/cli.py", line 341, in main
  File "site-packages/calibre/ebooks/conversion/cli.py", line 300, in create_option_parser
  File "site-packages/calibre/ebooks/conversion/plumber.py", line 734, in __init__
ValueError: No plugin to handle input format: doc
```

I haven't been able to find any answers or documentation about this.

I am using `shell_exec` to run this command via PHP.

I am using the latest release of calibre which is `1.45.0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calibre supports docx, not doc, according to https://bugs.launchpad.net/calibre/+bug/1206099.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, good find. I also found more documentation here about old .doc format. Maybe add to your question for others to see. http://manual.calibre-ebook.com/conversion.html#convert-microsoft-word-documents

Comment: There is a windows only plugin but its hardwired to go to HTML via docx.